# Ontario HST rebate: Do widowers fit into the "Couples" category, i.e. $1000?

Tags: canada, ontario, hst, rebate

There are 2 categories for the HST tax credit, that determines the dollar credit ie. $300 or $1000.  The categories are 1) A single person with no child or 2) Couples or Single Parents.  Would a widow/widower, fit into the second category of "couples", thereby entitling them to the $1000 <strike>per year</strike> amount?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Careful! – don't mix up the [GST/HST credit](http://www.servicecanada.gc.ca/eng/goc/gst_credit.shtml) (or the new [Ontario Sales Tax Credit](http://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/stc/index.html)) with the **Ontario Sales Tax Transition Benefit (OSTTB)**.  Each is a distinct program. The first two are ongoing and called *credits*, whereas the OSTTB is a "transition benefit" or "rebate".  I know, it's confusing! **:-/**

By the amounts you've mentioned, the $300 and $1000, I understand you to be referring to the **OSTTB**, and not the credit programs.  One more thing to clear up:  OSTTB payments are *not* yearly, but *one-time*.  There will be three payments, only: June 2010, December 2010, and June 2011.  Then it's *over*.

To answer your question:  Widows or widowers, in general, are classified as **single individuals** for the purposes of the OSTTB, *except* where the spouse died after December 31, 2009.

Refer to the Ministry of Revenue's FAQ, [Who is considered to be a single individual?](https://www.rev.gov.on.ca/en/credit/sttb/faq_eligibility.html#Q19)  Excerpt:

> **You are considered to be a single
>   individual, if** you are single,
>   separated, divorced, **or widowed**, and
>   you are 18 years of age or older and
>   do not live with any dependent
>   children under the age of 18.
>
> If you are married or in a common-law
>   relationship with any dependent
>   children under the age of 18, **and your
>   spouse passes away after December 31,
>   2009**, or you are a single parent
>   living with one dependent child under
>   the age of 18, and your child passes
>   away after December 31, 2009, **the
>   family rate will continue to apply for
>   your payments following the death.**
>
> *[emphasis mine]*